# Windows Media Foundation: IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType execution time issue

Tags: c++, winapi, image-processing, video, ms-media-foundation

I'm currently working on retrieving image data from a video capturing device.
It is important for me that I have raw output data in a rather specific format and I need a continuous data stream. Therefore I figured to use the IMFSourceReader. I pretty much understand how it is working. For the whole pipeline to work I checked the output formats of the camera and looked at the available Media Foundation Transforms(MFTs).

The critical function here is `IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType`. I'd like to elaborate one critical functionality I discovered. If I just use the function with the parameters of my desired output format, it changes some parameters like fps or resolution, but the call succeeds. When I first call the function with a native media type with my desired parameters and a **wrong** subtype (like MJPG or sth.) and call it again with my desired parameters and the **correct** subtype the call succeeds and I end up with my correct parameters. I suspect this is only true, if fitting MFTs (decoders) are available.

So far I've pretty much beaten the WMF to get what I want. The Problem now is, that the second call of `IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType` takes a long time. The duration depends heavily on the camera used. Varying from 0.5s to 10s. To be honest I don't really know why its taking so long, but I think the calculation of the correct transformation paths and/or the initialization of the transformations is the problem. I recognized an excessive amount of loading and unloading of the same dlls(ntasn1.dll, ncrypt.dll, igd10iumd32.dll). But loading them once myself didn't change anything.

So does anybody know this issue and has a quick fix for it?

Or does anybody know a work around to:

1. Get raw image data via media foundation without the use of`IMFSourceReader`?
2. Select and load the transformations myself, to support the source reader call?

Comment: Do you specify an RGB subtype in the second call to SetCurrentMediaType? That might be the cause for taking a long time to negotiate a format. If you try to specify NV12 it should be faster I think.

Comment: Yes, my target subtype is RGB, but I would be able to handle YUV aswell. You are right, if I specify NV12 or YUY2 the call does return way faster. I will try some different cameras. This could be the fix for me. Do you have any idea, why it takes so long for RGB. Does WMF iterate over all available Transforms (which are not including conversion to RGB) and afterwards checks, if conversion to YUY2 is available to convert to RGB in software?

Comment: It could be the hardware (video adapter) that is slow when finding a proper YUV to RGB conversion. What graphics adapter do you test with?

Comment: Currently I am testing with Intel HD Graphics 530. But the problem occurs on other hardware as well. Additionally I have the perception that the loading time depends on the camera I use. The call takes longer on a logitech c930e than a logitech c920. So it may be relevant how many native formats are supported. BUT I think that the c920 camera supports way more different formats configurations, which pretty much contradicts this line of thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since VuVirt does not want to write any answer, I'd like to add one for him and everybody who has the same issue.

Under some conditions the call `IMFSourceReader::SetCurrentMediaType` takes a long time, when the target format is RGB of some kind and is not natively available. So to get rid of it, I adjusted my image pipeline to be able to interpret YUV (YUY2). I still have no idea, why this is the case, but this is a working work around for me. I don't know any alternative to speed the call up.

Additional hint: I've found that there are usually several IMFTransforms to decode many natively available formats to YUY2. So, if you are able to use YUY2, you are safe. NV12 is another working alternative. Though there are probably more.

Thanks for your answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

You basically described the way Source Reader is supposed to work in first place. The underlying media source has its own media types and the reader can supply a conversion if it ever needs to fit requested media type and closest original.

Video capture devices tend to expose many [native] media types (I have a webcam which enumerates 475 of them!), so if format fitting does not go well, source reader might take some time to try one conversion or another.

Note that you can disable source reader's conversions by applying [certain attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389286) like `MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS`, in which case inability to set a video format directly on the source would result in an failure.

You can also read data in original device's format and decode/convert/process yourself by feeding the data into one or a chain of MFTs. Typically, when you set respective format on the source reader, the source reader manages the MFTs for you. If you however prefer, you can do it yourself too. Unfortunately you cannot build a chain of MFTs for the source reader to manage. Either you leave it on source reader completely, or you set native media type, you read the data in original format from the reader, and then you manage the MFTs on your side by doing `IMFTransform::ProcessInput`, `IMFTransform::ProcessOutput` and friends. This is not as easy as source reader, but is doable.

Comment: Okay, thanks, It really doesn't matter how complex the workaround is. The result matters. If I cannot find any other solution, I will try using the MFTs directly. Obviously I was not wrong in my description of the behavior of the source reader. Just wanted to check. The problem I pointed out was the duration of the setCurrentMediaType call, which is unbearable.

Comment: If source reader is unable to provide a conversion, it basically means that it tried to mount each and every of many advertised media types and failed with all of them. Yes, it could have taken some time to make sure there is no way to satisfy the given format requirements. For that reason you are basically supposed to use one of the native media types, or media type which is derived in a known way from one of those.